# A condition for relative gas

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics

Consider an ideal gas in a box. we know (no matter what, right?) that each massive particle's energy holds $E^2=c^2p^2+m^2c^4$ . how come that the condition for that gas to be relativistic is $E\approx mc^2$ ? isn't means that the particle's speed is low enough to neglect the kinematic energy, i.e the exact opposite?

Comment: Do you mean "relativistic gas?"  If so, you might consider a title change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the condition. The condition is that the non-relativistic kinetic energy is roughly equal to the $m c^2 $. This is shown below:

The energy of any particle indeed obeys $E = \sqrt{m ^2 c ^ 4 +p^2 c ^2}$. However, a Taylor expansion about $p =0 $ gives the usual non-relativistic relation as well as other higher order terms:
\begin{equation}
E = m c ^2 + \frac{p^2}{2m} -\frac{p^4 }{8m^3c^2} + ... 
\end{equation}
The first term is just the energy of the mass and the second term is the non-relativistic kinetic energy. We can ignore the remaining terms in the Taylor expand if 
\begin{equation}
\frac{p^2}{2m} \gg \frac{p ^4}{8m ^3c^2}
\end{equation}
or equivalently,
\begin{equation}
\frac{p^2}{2m} \ll 2mc^2 \sim mc^2
\end{equation}
where in the end we drop factors of two as we just want a rough estimate. So the condition to have a relativistic particle (and hence not be allowed to make the above approximation) is that the kinetic energy is roughly equal to the mass.

Comment: couldn't ask for a better answer, tanks. @jeffdror